# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in...` error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable in a function called `input_array` and sometimes it comes in like this: `student_selection_101,student_selection_50,tutoring_agreement` which is a string.

Later on, I do...

```
$.each(input_array, function(index, value) {
   //do stuff
}
```

I've done a million tests and iterations and I can't get away from getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in...` error.

I've tried getting `input_array` to become an object using the code below to avoid this dreaded error, but it's not working.  I've also read other answers saying that `JSON.parse()` is the key, but I don't know how to use it or what that means.

```
if(typeof input_array != 'object'){
    input_array = '"[' + input_array + ']"';
    alert(input_array);
    alert(typeof input_array);
}
```

I'd appreciate any help here.

Comment: And this is downvoted because.........

Answer (score -1):

hello my dear friend i'm didnt undrestand what are you looking for but i hope this works :

```js
var input_array = ['student_selection_101','student_selection_50','tutoring_agreement'];

var jsonFile = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input_array));
jsonFile.forEach(function(index,value){
   console.log(index,value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```